# Downloading an image from s3 using Axios

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, axios

I need to download an images from an s3 bucket that I control using Axios (client-side).  However, when I try to do so, I receive a generic 400 error without further explanation.  I've modified my CORS config on s3 to be very open, but still no luck.  Here's my CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And here is my Axios request

```
    let response = await axios.get(url, { // url is, of course, a link to an image on s3
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
```

---

Images can be viewed fine in-browser, and they can be downloaded via curl, so I know the images are valid.

Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @CanCelik in our case it was an issue with the accept headers in our Axios config.  As a troubleshooting step, try adding `headers: { Accept: '*/*' }` to the call that's giving you grief

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it out.

Comment: Did you fix it?